# Let the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ have positive radius of convergence $R$. Prove that $f^{'}(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Let the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ have positive radius of convergence $R$. Define $f:(-R,R)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$. Suppose that there is a sequence $(t_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ in $(-R,R)$ such that
(i) $\lim_{i\to\infty}t_i=0$
(ii) $t_i\neq0,\quad\forall i$
(iii) $f(t_i)=0,\quad\forall i$

Prove that $f'(0)=0$

So, I know we have to use these to prove it:
-theorem from the power series
-Sequence Criterion
-Sequence criterion for the limit definition

Please help

Comment: You don't just know $f'(0)=0,$ you know $f\equiv 0.$

Comment: what is the “theorem from the power series” ?

Comment: @C Squared, I should've said "a theorem that is related to the power series". It's one of the theorems that will be in this power series chapter: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch6.pdf

Answer (score 2):

We go to show that $a_{n}=0$ for all $n$. Hence $f=0$.

Prove by contradiction. Suppose that there exists $n$ such that $a_{n}\neq0$.
Let $n$ be the smallest integer such that $a_{n}\neq0$, then $f(x)=x^{n}(a_{n}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k-n})$.
For each $i$, $0=f(t_{i})=t_{i}^{n}\left(a_{n}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{k}t_{i}^{k-n}\right)$
which implies that $a_{n}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{k}t_{i}^{k-n}=0$
because $t_{i}\neq0$. Note that the function $t\mapsto\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{k}t^{k-n}$
is continuous at $t=0$. Since $t_{i}\rightarrow0$, we have that $0=\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\left(a_{n}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{k}t_{i}^{k-n}\right)=a_{n}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{k}0^{k-n}=a_{n}$,
which is a contradiction.